# Bash regex, a range

Tags: regex, bash

I have directiories in the form

```
test1trail1
test1trail2
....
test10trail10
```

how can I loop through directories test1trail1 to test9trail10, I would like to exclude test10 directories.

Comment: thanks, that does it. Have been using {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
test[1-9]trail(10|[1-9])$
```

This regex matches the strings which has a single digit (1 to 9) exists just after to `test` substring.